# Could not execute method of the activity using aws sS3Client

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a list of files from an S3 bucket in AWS.  These are files that I can successfully transfer to an AWS s3 bucket.  They are stored in the root folder of the S3 bucket.

As a baseline I am using the S3 Transfer Demo from the AWS github.  The problem is when I try to use sS3Client.listObjects ...
to get a list of file on the S3 bucket I get a runtime fatal error.

This is the method that I am trying execute:

```
public static List listFileInBucket() {
    sS3Client = getS3Client(MyApplication.getAppContext());
    List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = new ArrayList<S3ObjectSummary>();
    if(sS3Client != null) {
    summaries = sS3Client.listObjects(Constants.BUCKET_NAME,Util.getPrefix(
                MyApplication.getAppContext())).getObjectSummaries();

    }
    else {
        summaries = sS3Client.listObjects(Constants.BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.US),Util.getPrefix(
                MyApplication.getAppContext())).getObjectSummaries();

    }
    return(summaries);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the stack trace?  Also the if/else statement doesn't make any sense.

```
 if(sS3Client != null) {
summaries = sS3Client.listObjects(Constants.BUCKET_NAME,Util.getPrefix(
            MyApplication.getAppContext())).getObjectSummaries();

}
else {

 The S3Client is null, this call will not work.

    summaries = sS3Client.listObjects(Constants.BUCKET_NAME.toLowerCase(Locale.US),Util.getPrefix(
            MyApplication.getAppContext())).getObjectSummaries();

}
```